# Ubuntu hibernate resume fails: "PM: Resume from disk failed"

Tags: ubuntu, hibernate, suspend

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 10.4 from 9.10, and it's now hiding the hibernate and suspend options. How do I get them back?

**So the way you do this is make sure that your swap partition is in /etc/fstab and swap is enabled, and big enough. Look at `/proc/swaps` to see if anything is listed.**

Now I'm getting this error when I boot after suspending:

`init: ureadahead-other main process (705) terminated with status 4`

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I'm using Ubuntu with kernel `2.6.32-22-generic`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a `resume=` line in your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` for grub2, or `/boot/grub/menu.lst` for grub.

You should have lines that say:

```
linux (blah blah blah) root/dev/$ROOT_PARTITION resume=/dev/$SWAP_PARTITION
```

Or if you're using UUIDs, obtained from running `sudo blkid`:

```
linux (blah blah blah) root=UUID=$UUID_ROOT_PARTITION resume=UUID=$UUID_SWAP_PARTITION
```

Where all words like `$WHATEVER` are either device nodes or partition UUIDs.

Comment: thanks much. I'd only been searching for that bit of magic for a month ;)

Comment: I asked the grub developers and they said it has nothing to do with the bootloader. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see a battery / plug icon in the tray? If no, GNOME power manager is probably not running, so you need to start it / add it to the tray. If yes, does it show the hibernate option?

As a workaround, you can also suspend/hibernate from the CLI:

```
acpitool -s #suspend
acpitool -S #hibernate
```

Comment: pm-hibernate  #--help for options |||
pm-suspend #--help for options

Comment: does acpitool work for shutdown as well?

Comment: @Dom: No. That's what `shutdown` is for :-) (most modern Linux distros also have `poweroff`).

Comment: Oops! Thanks, didn't know those.